# Format jaxb element Date

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling

I have jaxb class like below, where i want my xmlAdapter format the date value, i am getting the exception?

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Invalid @XmlElementRef : Type "class java.lang.String" or any of its subclasses are not known to this context.

what is wrong with the below code?

### Jaxb class

```
@XmlElementRef(name="endDate")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)
protected JAXBElement<Date> endDate;
```

### DateAdaptor class to format the jaxbelement date value

```
    public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, JAXBElement<Date>>
    {
    private final String TIMEZONE_US_EASTERN = "US/Eastern";

    private final String LOCALE_LANGUAGE_EN = "en";

    private final String LOCALE_COUNTRY_US = "US";

    private final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";

    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = null;

    private TimeZone timeZone = null;

    private Locale locale = null;

    public DateAdapter() {
        locale = new Locale(LOCALE_LANGUAGE_EN, LOCALE_COUNTRY_US);
        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT,locale);
        timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(TIMEZONE_US_EASTERN);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(JAXBElement<Date> v) throws Exception {
        String timezone = getBasisForGivenDate(v.getValue());
        String startDayTime = "T23:59:59"+timezone;
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(timeZone);
        return dateFormat.format(v)+startDayTime;
    }


    @Override
    public JAXBElement<Date> unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return null;
    }


    public String getBasisForGivenDate(Date date) {

        String basis = "-05:00";
        TimeZone jvmTimeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();

        if (jvmTimeZone.inDaylightTime(date)) {
            basis = "-04:00";
        }
        return basis;
    }
 }
```

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: Update the question with the exception

Comment: Please add marshalling code, how do you create JAXBContext?

Comment: return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(JaxbObject).build();

Comment: Are you sure about XmlElementRef annotation? Try to change it to XmlElement

Comment: i am sure about the XmlElementRed annotation, it was intentional for my use.

Comment: But problem in XmlElementRef, i am pretty sure of it. I just wrote unit test and marshalling work with XmlElement and don't work with XmlElementRef. Also you have error in dataAdapter - `dateFormat.format(v)` should be `dateFormat.format(v).getValue()`

Answer (score 0):

There is two possible decisions:

1. Just replace @XmlElementRef to @XmlElement and replace `dateFormat.format(v)` to `dateFormat.format(v).getValue()` in marshal method.
2. If you are using ObjectFactory for object creation, something like

   ```
   @XmlRegistry
   public class ObjectFactory {

   @XmlElementDecl(name = "endDate", scope=EntityTest.class)
   JAXBElement<Date> createEndDate(Date value) {
       return new JAXBElement<Date>(new QName("endDate"), Date.class, value);
   }
   ```

   }

and Entity class is

```
    @XmlRootElement
    public class EntityTest {

    @XmlElementRef(type=JAXBElement.class, name="endDate")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)
    protected JAXBElement<Date> endDate;


    public void setEndDate(JAXBElement<Date> endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }
}
```

then your DateAdapter should be something like this:

```
public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<JAXBElement<String>, JAXBElement<Date>> {
    private final String TIMEZONE_US_EASTERN = "US/Eastern";
    private final String LOCALE_LANGUAGE_EN = "en";
    private final String LOCALE_COUNTRY_US = "US";
    private final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = null;
    private TimeZone timeZone = null;
    private Locale locale = null;

    public DateAdapter() {
        locale = new Locale(LOCALE_LANGUAGE_EN, LOCALE_COUNTRY_US);
        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT, locale);
        timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(TIMEZONE_US_EASTERN);
    }

    @Override
    public JAXBElement<String> marshal(JAXBElement<Date> v) throws Exception {
        String timezone = getBasisForGivenDate(v.getValue());
        String startDayTime = "T23:59:59" + timezone;
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(timeZone);
        return new JAXBElement<String>(v.getName(), String.class, dateFormat.format(v.getValue()) + startDayTime);
    }

    @Override
    public JAXBElement<Date> unmarshal(JAXBElement<String> v) throws Exception {
        return null;
    }

    public String getBasisForGivenDate(Date date) {
        String basis = "-05:00";
        TimeZone jvmTimeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();

        if (jvmTimeZone.inDaylightTime(date)) {
            basis = "-04:00";
        }
        return basis;
    }
}
```

note: `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread safe and use it in singleton will cause bugs in multithread environment.

Unit test for check it work:

```
@Test
public void testMarshaler() throws Exception {
    EntityTest entity = new EntityTest();
    JAXBElement<Date> date = new ObjectFactory().createEndDate(new Date());
    entity.setEndDate(date);
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(EntityTest.class, ObjectFactory.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, false);
    marshaller.marshal(entity, System.out);

}
```